# Difference in output with map and each

Tags: ruby, dictionary, each

I need help figuring out why there are differences between map and each in my following code.

```
j = "This is an awesome string"

j.split('').map do |char|
    char.next! if char =~ /[A-Za-z]/
end
```

This returns:

```
["U", "i", "j", "t", nil, "j", "t", nil, "b", "o", nil, "b", "x", "f", "t", "p", "n", "f", nil, "t", "u", "s", "j", "o", "h"]
```

but

```
j.split('').each do |char|
    char.next! if char =~ /[A-Za-z]/
```

returns:

```
["U", "i", "j", "t", " ", "j", "t", " ", "b", "o", " ", "b", "x", "f", "t", "p", "n", "f", " ", "t", "u", "s", "j", "o", "h"]
```

Why does the change from `map` to `each` remove the nil?

Comment: As always, there's a oneliner for this in ruby: `"This is an awesome string".gsub(/[A-z]/) { |c| c.next }` Not strictly relevant to the question, but worth knowing nonetheless (I think, anyway).

Comment: @asQuirreL On your way.. `"This is an awesome string".enum_for(:gsub, /[a-z]/i).map(&:next)` ... Hope you would like. It actually #map, which will show you what it has done, during iteration. :-)

Comment: Similarly, there is `This is an awesome string".gsub(/[A-z]/, &:next)` (The problem with your solution is that it actually removes non alphabetic characters, rather than ignoring them).

Comment: @asQuirreL It is #gsub.. Not #gsub! ..No worry. :-)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Because [`Array#each`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.2/Array.html#method-i-each) returns the *receiver* itself. But [`Array#map`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.2/Array.html#method-i-map), *maps*, each current character, you passed to the block, with the current computation result.

With `#map`, the condition `if char =~ /[A-Za-z]/` evalutated as *falsy*, for each passed element like `" "`. Thus block mapped `nil` while it founds `" "` or any element for which `if` condition evaluated as *falsy*. But `#each` forgets about the block result after each *iteration* is completed, But `#map` doesn't.

If you look at the output, you can see all `nil`(s) are in the same position of `" "`. This observation also dictates about the behaviour I just mentioned above.

In Ruby, every block of code, like definition of class, method definitions, block definitions returns its last statement. In your `#map` block, there is no statements, after the `if modifier`, so it reruns `nil`.

In Ruby >= 2.1.1 I saw method to returns its names as a symbol. But when you will invoke it, then it will return its last statement. If the method body is empty, then `nil`.

Look below :-

```
[1] pry(main)> def foo
[1] pry(main)* end  
=> :foo
[2] pry(main)> foo
=> nil
[3] pry(main)> def baz
[3] pry(main)*   12
[3] pry(main)* end  
=> :baz
[4] pry(main)> baz
=> 12
```

**update**

From the comment of [*@asquirrel*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24647383/difference-in-output-with-map-and-each/24647470#comment38208081_24647383), I got an idea. You could write your code a more Ruby way :-

```
"This is an awesome string".gsub(/[a-z]/i).map(&:next)
# => ["U", "i", "j", "t", "j", "t", "b", "o", "b", 
# "x", "f", "t", "p", "n", "f", "t", "u", "s", "j", "o", "h"]
```

**update1**

```
j = "This is an awesome string"

array = j.split('').map do |char|
  char =~ /[A-Za-z]/ ? char.next : char
end

p array 

# >> ["U", "i", "j", "t", " ", "j", "t", " ", "b", "o", " ", "b", 
# "x", "f", "t", "p", "n", "f", " ", "t", "u", "s", "j", "o", "h"]
```

Comment: What if I didn't want it to replace the space and instead ignore and leave it?

Comment: so my update prevented the new code from remaining a clean one liner?

Comment: @user2801122 Write it in one line using `{ ..}`, It will become a one liner.. :-) Remove `do..end`/